# IE -SCRIPT5: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a link to page A from page B. Both the pages are on different servers but same domain. When I launch page A by clicking the link on page B, the page comes up fine. And then I browse page A site. On one of the pages there is file upload, clicking on the upload gives me error: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

If I launch application A by pasting the link in the browser, file upload works without any issues. There are no iframes or cross domain issues here. File upload action is pointing to the same domain. Plain javascript, no jquery is used on the page. The javascript on the file upload button click is:

```
onclick="this.form.pageButton.value=this.name; 
form.action='/FileUploadManage/Main?Action=myFileUploadAction';submit();"
```

I have gone through all the posts on this topic, but none explains this issue. The same issue is there on IE 7,8 and 9. Works well on firefox.

Comment: `this.form.submit()` perhaps?

Comment: yes, this.form.submit() is the line that generates the error. I am not able to understand why this errors.

Comment: You don't have `this.form.submit()`, you have `submit()`. I was suggesting you change it

Comment: no success with this.form.submit(). If I don't select any file and then click Upload there is no javascript error. The request goes to the server. It is only when there is a file selected that browser gives this error.